# how do I format a date in the local database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

how query command to format the date in the local database VB.NET?

I tried this syntax but it does not work

```
SELECT id_playlist, nama_playlist, playlist_date FROM tbl_playlist
WHERE (format(playlist_date, 'mm / dd / yyyy') = format(Now, 'mm / dd / yyyy'))
```

Comment: If you're trying to find rows which have a `playlist_date` of "today" (at any time), you should be thinking about finding formulas to create "today at midnight" and "tomorrow at midnight", as *datetime* values, and then use those in a comparison. About the *worst* thing you can do is to instead force conversions to strings, where all of a sudden you have to concern yourself with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `CONVERT(date, playlist_date, 101)`?